# CCK form to edit single field or set of fields

Tags: entities

We have a fairly large CCK content type and would like to be able to edit a single field of the node at a time (or a set of fields).

For example, we will display our content on the page through a custom view, with a series of "edit" icons per row, allowing the user to edit an individual fields values.

Ideally we are aiming to have a popup with that fields form item(s), which the user can edit and click update.

Manipulating the form after build is not practical as its so much overhead just to render a form with a single field.

Is there a module that can render a form for one or a series of the fields for the given node?

Answer (score 1):

Is it for D6, if so this module will solve your problem: [jEditable inline content editing](http://drupal.org/project/jeditable).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Views and the [Editable fields module](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields)